# Mac cant kill tomcat process

Tags: intellij-idea, kill-process

I can't stop the tomcat8 in IDEA, even I use 'kill process' button , it can't works. Who can help me?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3d18d.png)
My IDEA's version is 2017.2.5.

Answer (score 2):

I usually run this: `lsof -n -i4TCP:$PORT | grep LISTEN` from command line

Where I replace `$port` with 8080 for example.

Example output:

```
java      20561  pim   80u  IPv6 0x85f7db71b181d26b      0t0  TCP *:8080 (LISTEN)
```

And then kill the process manually (the PID is 20561 in this example) with:

```
kill -9 20561
```

Comment: Thank you.I had used this way,but it stills doesn't work.

Comment: if that doesn't work it looks like the process is really stuck and I suggest a reboot. If it happens more often I suggest upgrading IntelliJ and tomcat if possible

Comment: So just to confirm, you can never stop the tomcat process from intelliJ, but you are able to kill it using other means (command line, process manager etc.)?

Comment: btw... I believe that skill indicates it's send the kill signal but it's waiting for it to stop... for example if you have a suspended JVM because it's waiting on a breakpoint... it will "hang". Can you try it with another simple basic app that does pretty much to nothing?